# Create list from JSON objects

Tags: jquery, json

I need to create a list on the form

```
<li>
    <span class="room">A20</span>
    <span class="dropin">3</span>
    <span class="appoint">1</span>
    <span class="delay">20</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="room">A21</span>
    <span class="dropin">2</span>
    <span class="appoint">1</span>
    <span class="delay">10</span>
</li>
```

using the values from a json object on the form.

```
data = [
    { "name": "A20 Dropin", "queueType": "QUEUE", "customers": 3, "delay": 0 },
    { "name": "A20 Appoint", "queueType": "APP_QUEUE", "customers": 1, "delay": 20 },
    { "name": "A21 Appoint", "queueType": "APP_QUEUE", "customers": 1, "delay": 10 },
    { "name": "A21 Dropin", "queueType": "QUEUE", "customers": 2, "delay": 0 }
];
```

The problem is getting the name (e.g. A20) from every other object but still getting the customers from every object.

- The delay always come from the APP_QUEUE.
- There's always a pair of rooms e.g. **A20 Dropin** and **A20 Appoint**
- The objects might not come in order, so I'd need to sort them some how first, possibly on the name.

I've set up [an example in jsfiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/27QCp/31/) But the code prints every object and not on the form I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//normalize the data
var map = {}, array = [];
$.each(data, function (idx, value) {
    var key = value.name.match(/^.\d+/)[0];
    var item = map[key];
    if (!item) {
        item = {
            key: key,
            name: value.name
        };
        map[key] = item;
        array.push(item)
    }
    if (value.queueType == 'QUEUE') {
        item.dropin = value.customers;
    } else if (value.queueType == 'APP_QUEUE') {
        item.appoint = value.customers;
        item.delay = value.delay
    }
})

var html = $.map(array, function (item) {
    return '<li><span class="room">' + item.key + '</span><span class="dropin">' + item.dropin + '</span><span class="appoint">' + item.appoint + '</span><span class="delay">' + item.delay + '</span></li>';
}).join('');
$('ul').append(html);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jx4MT/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(data).each(function(i,v){
 var a = v.name.split()[0];
 var d = v.name.split()[1];
 var $span = $('span[data-a="'+a+'"]');
 var $li = null;
 if(span.length){
   $li = $span.closest('li');
 }
 else{
   //create li and whole of the structure
   $li = $('<li></li>');
 }

 //do rest of the dom changes here based on the value of d
 ....
 //at last
 $cont.append($li)/*the container element*/
});
```